# Swift 2 to Swift 3: Cannot convert value of type '(Data?, NSError?) -> Void' to to expected argument type 'GTMSessionFetcherCompletionHandler?'

Tags: swift, handler, swift3

I just updated a working Swift 2 to Swift 3 program, and I am getting the error,

> Cannot convert value of type '(Data?, NSError?) -> Void' to expected argument type 'GTMSessionFetcherCompletionHandler?'

Here are the relevant details (I hope):

```
let fetcher = GTMSessionFetcher(urlString:url)
fetcher.authorizer = parentController.service.authorizer
fetcher.beginFetch(completionHandler: handleDownload(studentNum))
                                      ^^^^ causing the error
```

The function for the completionHandler:

```
func handleDownload(_ studentNum:Int) -> (Data?, NSError?) -> Void {
    return { (data: Data?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        // code for function
    }
}
```

`GTMSessionFetcherCompletionHandler` is defined in an Objective-C header, as follows:

```
#define GTM_NULLABLE_TYPE __nullable
typedef void (^GTMSessionFetcherCompletionHandler)(NSData * GTM_NULLABLE_TYPE data,
                                               NSError * GTM_NULLABLE_TYPE error);
```

I have tried changing handleDownload() to the following:

```
func handleDownload(_ studentNum:Int) -> (GTMSessionFetcherCompletionHandler?) {
    return { (data: Data?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
       // code for function
    }
}
```

but that moves the error down to this function: "Cannot convert return expression of type '(Data?, NSError?) -> Void' to return type 'GTMSessionFetcherCompletionHandler?'"

I can't figure out how to keep the curried (?) data and error variables, and have it compile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [SE-0112](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0112-nserror-bridging.md), `NSError` is now bridged to Swift as the [`Error`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/error) protocol. In fact, if you <kbd>⌥</kbd> + click on the `GTMSessionFetcherCompletionHandler` type in Swift, you'll see exactly how it's bridged:

```
typealias GTMSessionFetcherCompletionHandler = (Data?, Error?) -> Void
```

Therefore you simply need to change your `handleDownload(_:)`'s signature to reflect this:

```
func handleDownload(_ studentNum:Int) -> (Data?, Error?) -> Void {
    return { (data: Data?, error: Error?) -> Void in
        // code for function
    }
}
```

Comment: I should add -- this affected other parts of my code, too -- I had forced some code to use NSError, and it caused a runtime error. I would not have figured out the runtime error without your response. So thank you!

Comment: @ChrisGregg Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  WORequestManager.shared().genericRequest(withMethod: "GET", webserviceName: walletAPI, andParameters: params, showLoading: true, success: { (responseDictionary: [AnyHashable: Any]?) in


        }, failure: { (error: Error?) in

    })
```

Comment: While this code snippet may answer the question, it doesn't provide any context to explain how or why. Consider adding a sentence or two to explain your answer.